# Titanium: Facebook API: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium

Following the standard example from the docs, but it's not working.

Funny thing is that if I do Ti.API.info(fb.getPermissions()), publish actions is listed.

Here's the output from that line:

```
[INFO] :   permissions=
[INFO] :   publish_actions,status_update,publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages
```

Code:

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = '1234567';
fb.permissions = ['publish_actions', 'status_update', 'publish_stream', 'read_stream','manage_pages']; // Permissions your app needs
fb.authorize();

fb.forceDialogAuth = true;

var data = {
    caption: 'This is a test',
    picture: blob
};

fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/photos', data, 'POST', function(e){
    if (e.success) {
        alert("Publish is ok");

    } else {
        if (e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert("Unkown result");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`publish_stream` is deprecated since years, and competely senseless if you use `publish_actions` anyway.

That being said, the error message means that the authorization process was not successful. If you are trying as Admin of the Facebook App, you should debug your Access Token after authorization, and make sure that you get asked for the permissions in the process.

If you are NOT trying with an Admin/Developer/Tester of the App, it is most likely because the permissions need to get approved in the Login Review first: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: The thing it, it works as admin, but not as another user.
So i need to submit it for review then?

Comment: yes, of course. you MUST go through the review process with most permissions since april 2014, else they will only work as admin. the correct answer is the last paragraph of my answer then.

Comment: Ok, submitted for review. As soon as i can confirm this, i will award correct answer.